# Exim: how to deliver locally and send a copy to another server

Tags: exim

I need to configure exim to deliver messages to domain abc.com and send a copy to another server, which is also configured for abc.com.

Something like that:

```
user@gmail.com sends email to test@abc.com

abc.com mx resolves to 200.200.200.10 ( one of the exim servers )

Message is delivered

Exim receives the message locally AND send a copy to 200.200.200.50
```

I tried to setup a smarthost:

```
        smarthost:
                driver = manualroute
                domains = abc.com
                transport = remote_smtp
                route_data = "200.200.200.50"
```

It does deliver to the other server but it doesn't save the message locally.

Any ideas of what i can do?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be possible with a shadow_transport.  Leaving a comment rather than an answer since I'm not 100% certain how to implement them.  Shadow_transport listed here http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch24.html

Comment: Also, there's the unseen option for routers - "You can force an address to continue through the routers even if it has been accepted by using the unseen option"

Comment: @EightBitTony Thank you! The unseen option did the trick. If you answer the question, i can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Answered below, glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `unseen` keyword on routers.

> When this option is set true, routing does not cease if the router
>   accepts the address. Instead, a copy of the incoming address is passed
>   to the next router ...

from [Generic options for routers](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch15.html).

I think try,

```
smarthost:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = abc.com
  transport = remote_smtp
  route_data = "200.200.200.50"
  unseen
```

Before the other routers?